# How to use a select option value as a PHP variable in the next query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which provides a drop down list of all the rows in that specific table, this works fine.  The code is below:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, NAME FROM b_sonet_group ORDER BY ID DESC");

echo "<select>";
echo "<option value=''>Select Your Project</option>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

  {
  echo "<option value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['NAME'] . "</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I now want a second drop down list that is determined by what ever is selected in the one above based on the ID.  So, I want something like:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, ALBUM_NAME FROM a_different_table WHERE ID=ID_FROM_QUERY_ABOVE");

echo "<select>";
echo "<option value=''>Select Your Album</option>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

  {
  echo "<option value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['ALBUM_NAME'] . "</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I basically want to get the ID from the first drop down to provide the results in the second dropdown.  Can this be done?

Comment: You can do this only using AJAX.

Comment: Oh right, I don't know anything along those lines, may have to think of an alternative.  Is there anyway of getting the ID of the chosen value to use elsewhere on the page?  Like $projectid= the selected id from the dropdown?

Comment: "Only" being if you want to have the second drop down box on the same page... Otherwise you can just process the result in a new page.

Comment: @AndyNaylor: with AJAX... Because PHP is processed on the **server**. That means you'd have to make a request to the server. JavaScript is executed on the **client** machine.

Comment: It's not a big deal to trigger this with jQuery.

Comment: Yes.. That is the alternative I'm going to go for.. Add a Step One > Step 2 and carry the values through doing it that way. Cheers for the point in the right direction.

Comment: He can also do a page reload, submitting a form, and not doing the first query if it's already done xD also as people suggested doing it in jQuery ajax will be easy, I suggest you to have a look to jquer's ajax documentation

Comment: Do you want the action to happen when something is selected form the first select or would it be possible for the user to hit a submit button after their first selection?

Comment: If the user can hit a submit button and carry the value to the next page.  I've tried this with a POST and then adding name='ID' and then $ID = $_POST['ID']; on the next page and then echo'ing $ID but I get nothing, what am I missing

Answer (score 2):

You can't "only" do this with Ajax, but you should do it with Ajax.

PHP way (not suggested, and untested). Basically use isset and if it is, more will be added to the form. The POST from the select, is the select name. So change the plain select tag which I did in the example below. This also requires them to submit it.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, NAME FROM b_sonet_group ORDER BY ID DESC");

echo '<form id="project_form" method="post">';
    echo "<select id='select_your_project' name = 'select_your_project'>";
    echo "<option value=''>Select Your Project</option>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

      {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['NAME'] . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";

    if(isset($_POST['select_your_project'])){
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, ALBUM_NAME FROM a_different_table WHERE ID='".$_POST['select_your_project']."'");
        echo "<select id='select_your_album' name = 'select_your_album'>";
        echo "<option value=''>Select Your Album</option>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))

          {
          echo "<option value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['ALBUM_NAME'] . "</option>";
          }
          echo "</select>";
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
echo '</form>';

if(isset($_POST['select_your_album'])){
    //do form submitted stuff here
}
```

Ajax way (two separate files, untested but gives you the idea)

```
//Main page (view) START
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //this will trigger automatically when they change the first select box
    $('#select_your_project').on('change', function(event){
        if($(this).val() == 'select_your_project'){
            $("#ajax_reply_div").empty()
        }else{
            var values = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "php_data_file.php",
                type: "post",
                data: values,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#ajax_reply_div").empty().append(data);
                },
                error:function(){
                    $("#ajax_reply_div").empty().append('something went wrong');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

<form id="id_of_form">
    <?php
    echo "<select id='select_your_project' name='select_your_project'>";
    echo "<option value='select_your_project'>Select Your Project</option>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

      {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['NAME'] . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";
    ?>
    </select>
    <div id="ajax_reply_div">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

//Main page (view) END

//php_data_file.php START

if(isset($_POST['select_your_project'])){
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, ALBUM_NAME FROM a_different_table WHERE ID='".$_POST['select_your_project']."'");
    //as a note it is better to only send an array back then build the HTML with jQuery, but this way is easier if you are new to jQuery/Ajax
    echo "<select id='select_your_album' name = 'select_your_album'>";
    echo "<option value=''>Select Your Album</option>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
      echo "<option value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['ALBUM_NAME'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

//php_data_file.php END
```